# I feel like that misinformation feels too artificial as a plot-driving force in my story, how can it be more natural?

Tags: creative-writing, plot

Misinformation is an important element of my story as is pretty much kicks the plot in motion:

*Gyvaris, a young dragon, steals a sheep from a large flock since he's really hungry and just couldn't find a single deer, though he was sure there were more than enough for him in the forest.*

*A shepherd witnesses the event and rumor soon starts to spread about a fearsome monster that ravages the countryside. People blame missing livestock on the dragon. The breaking point comes when a child goes missing in the forest where Gyv was often seen.*

*The king orders his best knight to track down and kill the dragon. Gyvaris was chilling out on his perch and occasionally going on leisure flights while all this was going down. He only realizes something is amiss when a crossbow bolt buries into his neck...*

This gives a good motivation for humans to want to kill Gyv and a good reason for Gyv to view humans as dangerous and evil invaders, without making either of them unreasonably bad.

Yet it still tastes artificial. **The entire plot requires us to believe that people believed a single creature, they never knew or heard of before, just started doing horrible things, without evidence.**

As the writer and as my self-insert in the story, I get to influence how events unfold and occasionally give my pawns a little nudge.

**How can I use these tools to give events like the one in the bold text the illusion of being logical and "unavoidable"?**

Comment: Um, guys? When you cast Close votes, could you please give a reason?

Comment: In a lot of fantasy stories, people are afraid of dragons because of the myths surrounding them. Do these myths exist in your world as well? Maybe Gyvaris is unusual in that respect, or the myths themselves are painting a wrong picture about all dragons.

Comment: What does #MeToo have to do with anything and who is Alec Holowka?

Comment: Ummm, this is a story about farmers/ranchers who are blaming a dragon who already did steal and eat a sheep for stealing and eating other livestock and a sheep-sized human.  How exactly is this unbelievable?  In real life ranchers blame wolves for their losses and use it as an excuse to kill them without provocation.  The wolves in reality are only responsible for some of the losses.

Answer (score 14):

I think the problem here (and the reason the OP feels it "tastes artificial") is too much coincidence:

First, we have deer in the forest, but for some unexplained reason the dragon cannot find a single one, so he steals a sheep, and is so unlucky or careless doing it that he is seen by a shepherd. The fact that the deer are there and he can't find any seems too unlucky, piled on top of the bad luck of a witness.

Then the deer come back, and he doesn't have to steal sheep anymore? What caused them to disappear so long he grew hungry, then magically return?

Then livestock start disappearing? What is causing that? That is more extremely bad luck.

Then a child (too conveniently) goes missing? Why? That is more extremely bad luck.

If you are going to start a story with bad luck, make it **one** bad luck incident.

1) The Normal World: You have a dragon in a forest. He hunts deer. This is his normal world, he is happy and content, there are plenty of deer, he is in balance as the top predator in his environment. If you wish to make him smart and sympathetic, he takes deer intelligently: He only takes the old, ill and lame, he doesn't take fawns (as a lion or wolf would) and he doesn't take their mothers, or pregnant females, or young females. He culls his herd, killing quickly to minimize suffering.

2) The Inciting Incident: Humans hunt deer, too. They always have. A group of bowhunters happen to see your dragon take a deer, as it does every day, or once a week, or whatever. If they don't know what a dragon is, they start firing at the monster poaching their deer. Our dragon fights back in self-defense, the arrows hurt and could kill it. In fighting back he kills two of the hunters, and the rest scatter and flee.

3) The Escalation: The dragon doesn't understand the humans, and has to treat himself and heal his wounds. The humans return to their village, but now they have a monster that has killed two men, and it must be exterminated. It is too dangerous to let live! If you still want the kid involved, they bring it up: It flies, they saw it lift a deer! Surely it can snatch kids from the ground, or sheep. They create a posse to hunt it, and this dynamic drives our dragon out of his normal world. The dragon is not surprised by them, but terrified, still injured, and aims to escape. (I presume from your other questions he ends up captured, that is fine, the villagers intend to sell him or something.)

Thus ends Act I.

The only bad luck is the dragon was unlucky enough to be seen killing a deer. Human hunters naturally wander, follow spoor, and deers naturally forage and wander randomly in search of edible foliage. If you want to make this slightly more plausible, set it at the beginning of winter: The deer have to wander more to find food, the hunters want food to store for the winter so they are more persistent and work farther into the wood, and the dragon has to fatten himself up for winter as well, so he is eating and hunting more often.

Comment: If you don't like the idea of Gyvaris killing anyone, the hunters could also panic at just seeing a dragon (peacefully flying above the forest, or grabbing a deer and flying away) that could _potentially_ attack humans.

Comment: @Llewellyn In a story told from an intelligent dragon's POV, I don't think readers (or the author) should take issue with a dragon lashing out in self-defense and killing somebody that has shot it and is trying to kill it first. Its thoughts will prove it is just self-defense. Heck, I wouldn't have a problem with a **human** MC killing their human attacker in self-defense (some people might, but I wouldn't). As a reader, I certainly wouldn't blame the dragon. And I think an actual killing of a villager or two would be a more compelling reason to risk their lives than "we saw a monster."

Comment: @Amadeus I find that in large power-differential situations (Dragon vs Puny Hunters, for example) people are more willing to blame the one with power for escalating the situation, even if it is self-defense. We would not, for example, accept an adult killing a child because the child stabbed him with a pencil.

Admittedly, this does depend on how dangerous a dragon is compared to a human, and how well established this is.

Comment: @Onyz This OP has discussed this dragon in previous questions, I believe it is intended to be a small dragon, not much bigger than a horse. In which case it would be physically the underdog. Perhaps we can analogize to a contest like six archers making a surprise attack on a tiger, it would hardly be the tiger's fault if, having already taken a few arrows, she killed a few of these attackers while making her escape. Most importantly, when written from the **dragon's** POV, the reader absolutely ***knows*** it was self-defense. The reader, in the dragon's mind, is perfectly clear on its intent.

Comment: @Amadeus True enough about the POV being a powerful tool, but I think that establishing the extra information (this particular dragon is not a mighty beast of myth and legend like Smaug- it's a weak animal vulnerable to arrows) is what matters most for making the action not seem 'artificial' as the OP says. Even if the POV displays it as self-defense, the reader is able to question this POV if the facts as they know them do not match up with that POV. That is the core of an unreliable perspective, after all.

Comment: @Onyz I have no evidence that the dragon's POV is going to be an unreliable perspective. Nor do I understand how the dragon minding its own business, hunting for food and unaware of the hunters then getting shot, in what way does that not "match up" with the POV? The POV can be clear the dragon intended to harm the human that harmed him, the arrow near his heart almost killed him, and the human was about to shoot another. That is not an escalation, it is a response, and that is all my answer contemplates, a necessary lethal response to prevent humans shooting him **again** with lethal intent.

Comment: @Amadeus Yes, I suppose you could insert the necessary details into that POV narration as necessary. I hadn't considered that- fair enough. I suppose I incorrectly assumed that "POV" purely encompassed a first-person detailing of the thoughts of the perspective, but in hindsight that's definitely not always the case. My mistake.

Comment: See I didn't find it that much of the problem as in the wild, predators will typically stay away from humans in favor of their prey in the wild.  When the predator hits a streak of bad luck and gets hungry, it goes for humans or livestock to get a quick meal.  It's not ideal (in fact, from what I've heard, many animals don't like the taste of human flesh, but ya gotta eat) and dangerous, but if you can manage it and live, it will get you up to hunting form.  Additionally, the missing deer and the missing livestock and missing boy could be related to something else+

Comment: In ecology, only 10% of all energy is transferred up a food chain.   Most enegy enters the chain through plants, which the deer eat at a rate of 1 deer for every 10 plants consumed, and dragons eat deer at a rate of 1 dragon for every deer or 1 dragon for every 100 plants.   If something *else* that eats deer is in the dragon's territory, it causes an over hunt.  Most animals eat their favorite foods and will start looking for other things if desperate.  If the dragon is competing with a new predator, neither can get 10 deer and will branch out.+

Comment: +The Dragon may  be better at finding deer but hit a spot immediately after the unknown predator, and got desperate.   Meanwhile, the Dragon resumes eating deer and now the predator is desperate and going for sheep and later the "boy".  Additionally, this need not be an animal but a human behind the missing.   "Rustling" is a crime of stealing livestock and if a shepard boy saw them stealing the sheep, foul play and another plausible explanation would give them cover to keep on with their crimes.

Comment: @hszmv I don't think all that makes any difference if the OP is telling it from the dragon's POV. The dragon can't know all that stuff, so the reader doesn't know it, and it is the OP's job to assist the reader's imagination, it is not the reader's job to fill in the blanks in the story. That's not good writing. I stand by my advice, if the plot is driven by bad luck, there should be ONE incidence of bad luck, readers will find that plausible. (A gambling addict can have a string, as a consequence of one thing, being an addict.) for the dragon, 3 or 4 unexplained unusual events is implausible.

Comment: But that presupposes that the OP doesn't have a reasonable explanation for what he has stated as the issue.  Considering that the dragon and humans and livestock co-existed for all this time, and the dragons are only now known to humans, it's possible that deer hunting is much less favored to farming of animals for meat and other animal products.  Something new is introduced and is causing the humans to blame the dragon and the dragon to blame the humans.   We don't yet know the point, but it seems the set up is that both sides are acting on circumstantial evidence at best.  +

Comment: +In fact, the knight is firing on the dragon because from his perspective, he's a dragon.   The knight doesn't need any proof that it's the dragon that stole the kid.  The fact that the dragon killed a sheep is but did not kidnap the witness, as told from the POV of the dragon, means something or someone else took the kid.   It's not unreasonable at this jucture to assume there's some unknown agent that is at the very least, indirectly setting the dragon up for a crime he did not commit.  The Kingdom Civil Liberties Union should sue and have this errant Knight's sword and coat of arms for this

Comment: @hszmv Have your opinion, none of that is in the OP's question or setup, I am going by that, not by my own fantasy of what Mephistopheles is writing. I repeat, it is the **author's** job to make wild coincidences plausible, not the **reader's** job, and **as written** the story sounds like an implausible string of bad luck from the POV of the dragon, which he does nothing about. It makes no difference if there IS a plausible explanation, it alienates readers if the beginning is full of random bad luck and extraordinary coincidence. If this were told in a **flashback** with the understanding +

Comment: + Of what really happened, that would be different, the reader wouldn't be confused because the dragon would understand what was really going on and why it was confused at the time, but not now. Then the reader could relate. I don't think this works, as it is told in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Panics have deep roots. They don't come out of the blue. They arise out of our need to make sense of our lives, to find patterns in randomness. Pattern finding is how our brains work, and it serves us well most of the time. But faced with a series of unexplained events, we seek connections, and when a particular event suggest a connection, our brains latch on to it and we start to see connections everywhere.

One story of a dragon stealing a sheep gets the shepherd laughed at. But if then it gets connected to a bunch of other disappearances, it starts to become a pattern. You have part of that already, as subsequent events are attributed to the dragon. But you need to extend it into the past as well. You need to establish the events that are going to coalesce into a pattern when the dragon report comes in.

This is really just another aspect of foreshadowing. Stories are a function of our pattern-seeking brains. That is why stories are neater, simpler, and more focussed than ordinary life. They are part of how our brains make sense of our existence. Virtually anything can be made acceptable in a story if it fits a pattern that you have established by foreshadowing.

(To be clear, in your case, it is the panic that has to be foreshadowed, not the dragon snacking.)